# Creating interactive prototypes in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, interface, design, ux

I will be working on Ubuntu as a UX designer and was wondering if any other UXer in the same situation can recommend software to produce fairly advanced interactive prototypes. I'm thinking something similar to Axure, capable of handling more advanced functionalities like variables, interactive panels, etc. I'm not just looking for basic wireframes and clicking between them. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Balsamiq Mockups is available for linux, however be aware of [Adobe Air installation caveats](http://support.balsamiq.com/customer/portal/articles/99007-linux-installation-woes).